# What exactly are celery partials for?

Tags: celery

I didn't get the exact idea from [celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#partials) of what the celery *partials* are for. I may want to use that, but not sure if it my idea is correct.

Lets's say I have following two tasks:

- `add(a, b, c)`
- `multiply(d, e)`

Let's assume both tasks take a bit longer to complete. Is is possible to use partials to:

1. run `add(?, b, c)` in parallel with `multiply(d, e)`
2. pass the results of `multiply(d, e)` as the last argument to `add()`?

This way adding `b` and `c` and multiplication of `d` and `e` run in parallel and when both are done, only the result of multiplication is passed to the `add` task. This could save some time, because `b` and `c` sum is already computed and in the second step only `a` is added to the pre-computed result?

If so, how can I achieve that? I mean what is the way to wait in `add` task for the `a` argument to be provided? I tried, but didn't find any relevant docs on that topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have an incorrect idea about how celery partials work.

They can not be executed until all parameters have been specified.

If you do the following

```
ch = chain(multiply.s(d, e), add.s(b, c))
ch.apply_async()
```

what happens is that `multiply` is run asynchronously. Once it is done the result is passed to `add` which is then run asynchronously.

In order to achieve the parallelization you speak of you could use the following:

```
@app.task
def add(a, b):
     return a + b

ch = chord(group(multiply.s(d, e), add.s(b, c)))(add.s())
```

Comment: Okay, that's a bit pity, but thank you for the clarification!

Comment: updated answer to show approach you were looking for